# How do I allow users to add additional data to a mySQL users database table after they have already joined?

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new to PHP but am in the process of hacking together a web app focused around gardening. I followed a tutorial and built a registration and login system. I want the user in the app to be able to input additional data at a later date including fields like Postcode/Zip code and the ability for them to select 'Plants' to add to their account. I know how I create the form but I want to know how to add this data to the database so that it corresponds with their account details such as username which are already in the database.

Comment: You take the data and update the specific row in the database that you identify via the username/userID.

Comment: Please complete some tutorials and learn at least the basics. If you have specific questions later, please come back and ask.

Comment: you can ask these kind of question on here reddit.com/r/php or reddit.com/r/wedev you won't get answer to this question on this website. you need to provide some codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you have a column in the users table called 'id' or something similar which auto increments and is unique, this gives you a point of reference for each user.

When the user logs in, using his username and password, you can retrieve this id, and then use it throughout your app when working with the table or other tables that are related (using the id).

So if you were to add/update information in the table you'd use the user's id eg:

```
 UPDATE users SET postcode = 'sg12988' WHERE id = '8374'
```

You can read more about SQL commands [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/) or [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) .